# PostgreSQL - Query to show which time intervals contain data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains timestamped data.  I'm trying to construct a query that will return one row for each 5-minute interval, with a column which is `TRUE` if a timestamp falls in that interval and `FALSE` if none do, starting at the earliest timestamp in the data and ending at the latest.

I can get the 5-minute intervals containing timestamps like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('hour', t) + ( EXTRACT(minute FROM t)::int / 5 * interval '5 min' ) AS t,
       TRUE AS val
FROM data_table
ORDER BY t;
```

But how can I then fill this in with the intervals containing no data?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: outer join on generate_series I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need a function to round a timestamp down to the previous 5 minute boundary:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trunc_five_min(timestamp with time zone)
   RETURNS timestamp with time zone
   LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$$SELECT date_trunc('hour', $1)
         + date_trunc(
              'minute',
              ($1 - date_trunc('hour', $1)) / 5
           ) * 5$$;
```

This function will get inlined into the query, so you can see it as a notational shortcut.

When I have a time series table like this:

```
TABLE samples ORDER BY ts;

┌────────────────────────┐
│           ts           │
├────────────────────────┤
│ 2017-06-02 11:58:30+02 │
│ 2017-06-02 12:00:00+02 │
│ 2017-06-02 12:03:00+02 │
│ 2017-06-02 12:17:00+02 │
│ 2017-06-02 12:17:22+02 │
└────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

I can produce the desired result with this query:

```
WITH lim AS (SELECT trunc_five_min(min(ts)) AS min,
                    trunc_five_min(max(ts)) AS max
             FROM samples)
SELECT i.i AS interval_start,
       count(s.ts) AS num_samples
FROM lim
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(lim.min, lim.max, INTERVAL '5 minutes') i
   LEFT JOIN samples s
      ON s.ts >= i AND s.ts < i + INTERVAL '5 minutes'
GROUP BY i.i ORDER BY i.i;

┌────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│     interval_start     │ num_samples │
├────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 2017-06-02 11:55:00+02 │           1 │
│ 2017-06-02 12:00:00+02 │           2 │
│ 2017-06-02 12:05:00+02 │           0 │
│ 2017-06-02 12:10:00+02 │           0 │
│ 2017-06-02 12:15:00+02 │           2 │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, `generate_series` was the piece I was missing.  Somehow about 40 minutes of googling didn't turn it up, though of course now I know what to google for it is found easily.

Comment: Note also that the question includes how to truncate a timestamp to 5 minute resolution.